# Accessible, keyboard-friendly way to remove focus style from checkbox label after mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have styled `input:focus + label` to visually indicate when an input has been focused using keyboard navigation.

But Chrome (and maybe not just Chrome?) persists the `:focus` state after using a mouse to click the input, which looks ugly.

I want to remove the `:focus` styling after the click *without altering keyboard navigation*. i.e., when you move your mouse away after clicking a label, it should no longer be red.

I have seen suggestions to `.blur()` the input on mouseup; but 1) it hasn't worked for me (see snippet below), and 2) I'm concerned it will take keyboard navigation out of its usual flow.

Yes, someone using the mouse to click a checkbox and then going to keyboard navigation is an edge case. But it's one I would like to account for.

```js
$("label").mouseup(function () {
 $(this).blur();  // This has no apparent affect.
 $("#" + this.htmlFor).blur();  // Or this.
});
```

```css
input:hover + label, input:focus + label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>Form Part One</p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="cb" /><label for="cb1">First Checkbox</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="cb" /><label for="cb2">Second Checkbox</label>
  
  <p>Form Part Two</p>
  <input type="radio" id="r1" name="r" /><label for="r1">First Radio</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="r2" name="r" /><label for="r2">Second Radio</label>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the point of removing focus immediately after receiving focus? this would just blink the element red at whatever speed the user clicked the mouse.

Comment: This style is meant to indicate to the user that their click/keypress will select the input. It is technically true that, after clicking an input, tapping the spacebar would have its standard effect for that input, it seems logical to assume that the user is navigating the form with their mouse and doesn't need the hover/focus style to remain. I want a solution that both "looks right" to the mouse user and still functions well for someone who switches back and forth between mouse and keyboard.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to fix the issue in Chrome or are you looking for totally different implementations to bypass the problem altogether?

Comment: @TylerH ways to bypass the problem altogether. I just noticed the issue is the same in Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED** based on comment:

```js
//set checkbox hover
$("input").hover(function() {
  $(this).next("label").css("color", "red");
}, function() {
  $(this).next("label").css("color", "black");
});
//set label hover
$("label").hover(function() {
  $(this).css("color", "red");
}, function() {
  $(this).css("color", "black");
});
//set checkbox focusin focusout
$("input").focusin(function() {
  $(this).next("label").css("color", "red");
  $(this).next("label").siblings().css("color", "black");
});
//set checkbox label active on click
$('input:checkbox').on('click', function() {
  $(this).next('label').toggleClass('active');
});
//set radio label active on click
$('input:radio').on('click', function() {
  $(this).next('label').toggleClass('active');
  $(this).siblings().next('label').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>Form Part One</p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="cb" /><label for="cb1">First Checkbox</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="cb" /><label for="cb2">Second Checkbox</label>
  <p>Form Part Two</p>
  <input type="radio" id="r1" name="r" /><label for="r1">First Radio</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="r2" name="r" /><label for="r2">Second Radio</label>
</form>
```

Comment: I think my phrasing wasn't clear. Basically the end goal is to make the label no longer red after the mouse button comes up.

Comment: Well. After the mouse button comes up and you're no longer hovering.

Comment: looks really close... two shortfalls are 1) hover style isn't preserved after mousup *but while still hovered* and 2) setting styles element-wise isn't very scalable (imagine if I wanted four or five styles applied for `:hover`. But it's darn close. I'ma tweak it in JSFiddle and see if I can get it to 100%.

Comment: I'm seeing double at this point... does this look right to you? https://jsfiddle.net/98nfygq8/

Comment: I mistakenly said in a deleted comment I wanted the hover style to be persisted after click. It should actually go away after the cursor leaves the label... Take a look at this updated fiddle, I think it might be the ticket: https://jsfiddle.net/98nfygq8/1/

Comment: May seem like a lot of code compared to other answers, but it's really bulletproof, try clicking everywhere, checkboxes only, labels only and you'll see ;)

Comment: 99% perfect... the one issue is that on second click of an input, focus goes out when the mouse is down (black), then comes back when is is up (red). Not terrible, just odd.

Comment: @mac9416, that's becuase when it looses focus (on click),  the hover behavior kicks in if the cursor is above the label, what exactly would be the ideal case?

Comment: Ideally, the label would stay red while the mouse button is pressed. But it's not a big deal.

Comment: @mac9416, try now.

Comment: Excellent! I don't even see what the change was, but it sure worked. Thanks!

Comment: Removed focusout and placed it's behavior inside focusin for all label siblings of the selected one. Glad it worked, regards.

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding you here, but I think the issue is that you are putting your event trigger on the wrong element. Input is the parent of label in the case of your html structure, and is the active element upon which the mouseup event should trigger.

```js
  

$("input").mouseup(function () {
 $(this).blur();  // This has no apparent affect.
 $("#" + this.htmlFor).blur();  // Or this.
});
```

```css
input:hover + label, input:focus + label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>Form Part One</p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="cb" /><label for="cb1">First Checkbox</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="cb" /><label for="cb2">Second Checkbox</label>
  
  <p>Form Part Two</p>
  <input type="radio" id="r1" name="r" /><label for="r1">First Radio</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="r2" name="r" /><label for="r2">Second Radio</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense, but it doesn't remove the focus style if you select an input by clicking its label.

Comment: This solves the issue of the outline not disappearing, but not the issue of still being able to manipulate the clicked element with the keyboard. Any solution involving `blur()` will mess up keyboard navigation.

Comment: Oddly enough, Rory, Lowther's snippet navigates with Tab as expected even after `blur()`. If you click a radio button and then try to change the selection with keyboard arrow keys, it doesn't work... but Tab navigation is my primary concern anyway.

Comment: @mac9416 You are right, Tab still works after `blur` in Chrome. However, in Firefox, the focus stays on whatever element it was on previously instead of changing to the clicked element.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane groovy. Looks like this is gonna involve JS and a `.pseudo-focus` class.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a label for a checkbox, the focus is transferred to the checkbox. However, the focus will not have been transferred by the time the mouseup event listener fires. So you were clearing the focus on the wrong element, and even if you had tried to clear the focus for the correct element, that element would not yet have focus.

You can achieve the effect you're looking for by adding a momentary focus event listener on the checkboxes to immediately clear the focus inside your mouseup listener. This will only fire once the checkbox receives focus, and will only fire if there is a mouseup event, so it will not interfere with the keyboard users.

```js
$("label").mouseup(function () {
    $(this.previousElementSibling).one('focus', function() {
        $(this).blur();  // This has an apparent affect.
    });
});
```

```css
input:hover + label, input:focus + label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>Form Part One</p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="cb" /><label for="cb1">First Checkbox</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="cb" /><label for="cb2">Second Checkbox</label>
  
  <p>Form Part Two</p>
  <input type="radio" id="r1" name="r" /><label for="r1">First Radio</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="r2" name="r" /><label for="r2">Second Radio</label>
</form>
```